# How to request for login with email and plain text password in cakephp3

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, android-webservice, php-password-hash

I am new in **php** and working on **REST API in cakephp3** for my android application.

after setting up **php** and **composer** and routing I created **login function**..

```
public function login() {
    $this->request->allowMethod('post');
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $entity = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data, ['validate' => 'LoginApi']);
    if ($entity->errors()) {
        $this->httpStatusCode = 400;
        $this->apiResponse['message'] = 'Validation failed.';
        foreach ($entity->errors() as $field => $validationMessage) {
            $this->apiResponse['error'][$field] = $validationMessage[key($validationMessage)];
        }
    } else {
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        $password = $hasher->hash($entity->password);

        $user = $this->Users->find()
            ->where([
                'email' => $entity->email,
                'password' => $password
            ])
            ->first();
        if (empty($user)) {
            $this->httpStatusCode = 403;
            $this->apiResponse['error'] = 'Invalid email or password.';
            return;
        }
        $payload = ['email' => $user->email, 'name' => $user->name];
        $this->apiResponse['token'] = JwtToken::generateToken($payload);
        $this->apiResponse['message'] = 'Logged in successfully.';
        isset($user);
        isset($payload);
    }
 }
```

I use **123456** for **password** and this **hasher** returns random string every time, but the password which is already saved in database for **123456** is 
**$2y$10$f7K02jamD7ZeGHLcTkP6Weh6VsthMWHiwqHJmcqbsxuLCKGCQCGCu** this.

that is why it gives Invalid password in response.

My question is how to match the exact same string or hashing for request.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/9757856)

Use this line

```
password_verify($entity->password, $user->password)
```

instead of this

```
$hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
$password = $hasher->hash($entity->password);
```

you can try this function

```
public function login()
{
    $this->request->allowMethod('post');
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $entity = $this->Users->newEntity($this->request->data, ['validate' => 'LoginApi']);
    if ($entity->errors()) {
        $this->httpStatusCode = 400;
        $this->apiResponse['message'] = 'Validation failed.';
        foreach ($entity->errors() as $field => $validationMessage) {
            $this->apiResponse['error'][$field] = $validationMessage[key($validationMessage)];
        }
    } else {
        $user = $this->Users->find()->where(['email' => $entity->email])->first();
        if (count($user)) {
            if (password_verify($entity->password, $user->password)) {
                $payload = ['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $user->password];
                $this->apiResponse['token'] = JwtToken::generateToken($payload);
                unset($user->password);
                $this->apiResponse['response'] = array($user);
                unset($user);
                unset($payload);
            } else {
                $this->httpStatusCode = 403;
                $this->apiResponse['error'] = 'Incorrect password';
                return;
            }
        } else {
            $this->httpStatusCode = 403;
            $this->apiResponse['error'] = 'Email not found';
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be to hash according to a key you specify.

An advice would be to keep changing the key periodically. You will then need to dehash your save into the clear again using the old key then rehash on new.

I'm not sure if the option is available to you, so you might want to take it with a grain of salt.

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by "dehash"?

Comment: By dehash, I mean decrypt your hashed message. Bear in mind however that you cannot reverse a hash (it won't be a hashing function). For your need, you will have to use a cryptographic function with trapdoor

Answer (score 0):

First of all, CakePHP ships with authentication functionality out of the box, and I'd strongly suggest that you make use of that instead of running your own, given that it sounds as if you're looking for deterministic algorithms, this can very easily backfire.

If you are using CakePHP 3.5+, look into the [**authentication middleware plugin**](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication) (currently in RC phase), for earlier CakePHP versions, use the [**authentication component**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html).

For the sake of completeness, if you were to do this manually, you'd first query the user by its unique identifier (in your case the email address), and then compare the password at PHP level, using the password hashers `AbstractPasswordHasher::check()` implementation:

```
$user = $this->Users
    ->find()
    ->where([
        'email' => $this->request->data('email')
    ])
    ->first();

if (!$user ||
    $hasher->check($this->request->data('password'), $user->password) !== true
) {
    // authentication failed
} else {
    // authentication succeeded
}
```